# If InputBox matches any entry in column C, copy same row column Q to email body

Tags: excel, vba

I want to ask for the name of an employee, and then for every row where that name is in Column C, copy Column Q to the body of an email. There could be one, or many rows where this name occurs.

I thought I could use a vlookup. If I wanted to reference one it could work. I think I need some repetition in here but not 100% on hitting do/loop and so on.

```vb
NAME = Application.InputBox("Please enter the full name of the employee")

Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
'Dim zNAME As Excel.Range
Dim zDETAILS As Excel.Range
        
'On Error Resume Next
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
xMailBody = "Body content" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2"

On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
    .To = "EMAIL ADDRESS"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "EMAIL SUBJECT"
    'TBD. Need to insert Colum Q for every row where C matches 'NAME'
    
    .Body = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NAME, "C:Q", 14, False)
    
    '.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub copyFilteredColumn()
    
    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim outMail As Object
    Dim outMailBody As String
    Dim outInsp As Object
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim empName As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim nameRange As Range
    
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Initialize sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    ws.Range("R1:R" & ws.Rows.Count).Clear
    
    empName = InputBox("Please enter the full name of the employee")
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print lastRow
    
    With ws
        
        .Range("$A$1:$Q" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=empName
        .Range("Q1:Q" & ws.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        
        .Cells(1, 18).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        .ShowAllData
        
    End With
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print lastRow
    
    If lastRow > 1 Then
    
        Set nameRange = Range("R2:R" & lastRow)
        Debug.Print nameRange.Rows.Count

        nameRange.Copy
               
        Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        outMailBody = "Body content" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        
        With outMail
        
            .To = "EMAIL ADDRESS"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "EMAIL SUBJECT"
            
            'Insert column Q for every row where C matches 'empName'
            Set outInsp = .GetInspector
            Set wdDoc = outInsp.WordEditor
            
            wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore outMailBody
            wdDoc.Paragraphs(6).Range.Paste
            
            .display
            
        End With
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox empName & " not found."
    
    End If
    
    ws.Range("R1:R" & ws.Rows.Count).Clear
    
End Sub
```